# How exit from method in a switch expression?

Tags: java, switch-statement, conditional-statements, switch-expression

I'm studying switch expression, and I'd like to know how to pass control to the invoker method because "yield" just exits from the switch expression. I can't find any way to make it behave like the classic switch statement.

Is it even possible?

UPDATE: Here's a little piece of code.

```java
public static boolean isTimeToParty(DayOfWeek day) {
    boolean isParty = switch (day) {
        case MONDAY -> false;
        case TUESDAY -> {
            yield false; //return not allowed
        }
        case WEDNESDAY -> false;
        case THURSDAY -> false;
        case FRIDAY -> false;
        case SATURDAY -> true;
        case SUNDAY -> true;
    };
    return isParty;
}
```

What I mean is: How to avoid assigning value to a variable and then calling return [variable_name]?
I would like to return value and exit switch at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a little vague.  What's an "invoker method?"  If you're referring to the caller, you can simply `return`.

Comment: You can also show us some code that illustrates what you're talking about.

Comment: What is the difference between "pass control to the invoker method" and "exits from the switch expression"? Exiting from the switch is exactly what `break` does in "classic" switch expressions (i.e. switch statements).

Comment: The same as `...?... :... ` the switch _expression_ cannot return. It could have been allowed like `if (...) return false; yield true;` but really, that is awful.

Comment: Since the switch expression is an...expression, would typing it like: "return switch expression" do the trick? I tried on the IDE and it's working, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Unearthly Correct: you cannot put `return` inside the switch. In your case it is easier to just use `return switch (day) { ...` to avoid the assignment to `isParty`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the feedback! My question I think it's now answered then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you cannot use `return`  or `break` within the switch, it would be easier in your case to simplify with `return switch ...` directly:

```
public static boolean isTimeToParty(DayOfWeek day) {
    return switch (day) {
        case SATURDAY, SUNDAY -> true;
        default  -> false;
    };
}
```

Comment: How come one cannot use return or break inside switch? I added examples that do.

Comment: @Hiran Chaudhuri Your examples are the original form of switch statements - they allow break + return and cannot be assigned to a local variable. A switch expression however uses `->` or `yield` inside each case - every case must hand back a result of same type as the others so that the yielded value can be assigned into a local variable: `boolean isParty = switch(day) ...`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between switch statement and expression. I will emphasize that in my response.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `return` to the calling method. If you just want to stop processing further cases in the same switch, use `break`.
This and the below example apply to the switch **statement**, whereas the original question was releated to the switch **expression**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    switch(1) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Case one");
            // no break, so case processing goes one
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Case two");
            break; // we bail out here and do not process further cases
        default:
            System.out.println("Default case");
    }
    
    switch(2) {
        case 2:
            return;
        default:
            System.out.println("Default case");
    }
    
    System.out.println("This is the end - should not be printed");
}
```

generates output

```
Case one
Case two
```

Comment: Switch expression does not allow `return` and `break`.